# Assigning values to properties of a 'struct ** record'

Tags: c, pointers, struct, pointer-to-pointer

I'm having troubles understanding the C double-pointer concept. Essentially, I'm trying to write code which will check if `record_1` hasn't been set yet. If not, set it. If it has been set, we'll add a new `struct record newRecord` to the first records `.next` pointer.

**I'm using a double pointer because it's required by the professor**

I've tried using `firstRecord = malloc(sizeof(struct record*));` without any luck, as well as trying to dereference the `firstRecord`.

The while loop to iterate through the records located in the `addRecord` function also doesn't work as expected because I can't figure out how to deal with the double pointer.

```
struct record
{
    int                accountno;
    char               name[25];
    char               address[80];
    struct record*     next;
};

int addRecord (struct record ** firstRecord, int accountno, char name[], char address[])
{
    if (firstRecord == NULL)
    {
        // Segmentation Fault here
        // (*firstRecord)->accountno = accountno;
        // Assign the name to the newRecord
        // strcpy((*firstRecord)->name, name);
        // Assign the name to the newRecord
        // strcpy((*firstRecord)->address, address);
        // Initialize the next record to NULL
        // (*firstRecord)->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        // Define a new struct record pointer named newRecord
        struct record newRecord;
        // Assign the accountno of newRecord
        newRecord.accountno = accountno;
        // Assign the name to the newRecord
        strcpy(newRecord.name, name);
        // Assign the address to the newRecord
        strcpy(newRecord.address, address);
        // Initialize the next record to NULL
        newRecord.next = NULL;
        // Create a new record and add it to the end of the database
        struct record ** iterator = firstRecord;
        // Iterate through the records until we reach the end
        while (iterator != NULL)
        {
            // Advance to the next record
            *iterator = (*iterator)->next;
        }
        // Assign the address of newRecord to the iterator.next property
        (*iterator)->next = &newRecord;
    }

    return 1;
}

int main() {
    struct record ** firstRecord;
    firstRecord = NULL;

    addRecord(firstRecord, 1, "Foo", "Bar");
    addRecord(firstRecord, 2, "Foo", "Bar");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what is your exact problem? And what have you tried doing? (The shown code doesn't really do anything)

Comment: You're asking because you're trying to write a function to do that, by any chance? And you call it with address of a pointer?

Comment: As a rule of thumb: if you don't understand something, don't use it. There is absolutely no need for pointer-to-pointer in this code. So your problems of understanding it likely originates from the fact that it doesn't make any sense to use here.

Comment: You don't need a double pointer here.

Comment: If you are using a linked list data structure, using a double pointer is not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not just required by the professor, it's required by your application. You want to allocate memory, and set a pointer that's defined *outside* your function to point to that memory. So naturally, you need to refer to that pointer. And C allows you to do that via a pointer to a pointer.

So what you want your calling code to look like is this:

```
struct record * firstRecord = NULL;
addRecord(&firstRecord, 1, "Foo", "Bar");
addRecord(&firstRecord, 2, "Foo", "Bar");
```

You pass the address of the regular pointer, so that `addRecord` could write into it. And it does that by dereferencing its argument, like so:

```
int addRecord (struct record ** pFirstRecord, /* ... */ )
{
    if (pFirstRecord == NULL)
      return 0; // We weren't passed a valid address of a pointer to modify

    if(*pFirstRecord == NULL)
    {
      // Here we check if the pointed to pointer already points to anything.
      // If it doesn't, then proceed with adding the first record
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining what was going on!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a double pointer, a simple pointer is enough. First you need to ***dynamically allocate memory*** for a new record and then set values to it :

```
int main() {
    struct record *record1;
    record1 = NULL;

    if (record1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nrecord_1 is NULL\n");


        //dynamically allocate memory for record1
        record1 = malloc(sizeof(struct record);
        if (record_1 == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error allocating memory\n");
            return -1;
        }

        //set values to record1
        record1->accountno = ...;
        strcpy(record1->name, ...);
        strcpy(record1->address, ...);
        record1->next = NULL;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        //do the same for record1->next
        record1->next = malloc(sizeof(struct record);
        if (record1->next == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error allocating memory\n");
            return -1;
        }

        //set values to record1
        record1->next->accountno = ...;
        strcpy(record1->next->name, ...);
        strcpy(record1->next->address, ...);
        record1->next->next = NULL;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

But note that in the way this program is written, the `else` part will never be reached, as `record1` is always initialized to `NULL` and there is no form of iteration.

You can read [this link](https://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-the-functions-malloc-and-free) as a reference for structures and their memory allocation.